# Definition of nullity in linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

If the ker(T) = **0**, is the size of the basis 0 or 1?

These are the relevant texts:

[image]

and

[image]

I'm confused about c) and why it isn't one-to-one:

[image]

If the nullity is 1, does that mean ker(T) is not just = to **0**

Answer (score 1):

If $ker T=\{0\}$, the size of the basis is $0$, since the basis is the empty set.

In question c, T can't be one-to-one since the dimension of the domain is $3$, and the dimension of the codomain is $2$.

Actually, you can easily check the matrix of $T$ has rank $2$, hence is surjective, so its nullity is $1$.

Comment: What is the intuition behind this: "T can't be one-to-one since the simension of the domain is 3, and the dimension of the codomain is 2.". Can you show me an example?

Comment: If a linear map is one-to-one, linearly independent vectors remain linearly independent, hence the dimension of the image is equal to the dimension of the domain.  Isn't it clear?

Comment: It is not, since I am a beginner. Say a transformation transforms a vector (2,1,0) to (2,1), how do you know it's not one-to-one?

Comment: Because in the target space the dimension is $2$, which implies, among other things, that you can have more than two vectors linearly independent, whereas the domain has dimension $3$, which means it has bases of $3$ elements, and these three elements remain linearly independent by a one-to-one transformation, which would contradict dimension $2$.